# String is not recognized as datetime format asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, calendarextender

```
 objRA_Campaigns.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

asp.net calendar extender

```
<td style="padding-top: 5px; *padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 2px;" valign="middle">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxStyle"
                                    meta:resourcekey="tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFromResource1" 
                                    Width="282px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDateCampaignStart" runat="server" CssClass="imgbutton" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png"
                                    meta:resourcekey="imgDateCampaignStartResource1" />
                                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom" runat="server"
                                    Format="dd-MM-yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgDateCampaignStart" TargetControlID="tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom"
                                    Enabled="True">
                                </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                            </td>
```

Exception is string is not in date time format.

Comment: What is the value of your `tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom.Text` exacty?

Comment: @Soner Gönül e.g 23-03-2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CalendarExtender` has `dd-MM-yyyy` as format, and you're parsing it as `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`. Both formats should match for the parse to be possible.

Comment: Yes they should match but exception is string is not in date time format. @ken2k

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Sure, because the TryParseExact expects **exactly** the format you specified. As the "HH:mm:ss" part is missing, the parse processing fails.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad: Yes, because you provide a format string that does not match to the input string. Use `dd-MM-yyyy` for `DateTime.ParseExact` as well. Btw, if you don't use `InvariantCulture` all occurences of `/` will be replaced by your culture's actual date-separator (f.e. in germany it is the dot).

Comment: @ken2k how can i convert the format . what is the solution for converting a format i do not want the specific fomat.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Use "dd-MM-yyyy" for ParseExact, and just ignore the "HH:mm:ss" part, it'll be 00:00:00 by default if not specified.

Comment: @ken2k yes by defualt it is. But what if I want to convert one format into another ? for example dd-MM-yyyy => yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss . can I use some thing else than ParseExact(). Like parse or some thing else ? My point is How can i convert two formates into one anther ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad You don't _convert from one format to another_. The date it the same, it's just the _string representation_ that is different. Is your input string is just "23-03-2014", then parse it as "dd-MM-yyyy". If you want to display the Time part of your date, then specify it when you get the string representation of it: `myDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: DateTime getStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom.Text, GeneralSettings.objDefaultSetting.DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None); 
                    objRA_Campaigns.StartDate = (DateTime)getStartDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); cannot convert string to date time ? @ken2k

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Please read my comments carefully. `DateTime.Parse`/`ParseExact` returns a `DateTime` from a `String`. `DateTime.ToString` returns a `String` from a `DateTime`. There is a difference between the **date itself** (that is ALWAYS the same and doesn't depend on any format) and its **string representation** that depends on the format you specified for both `Parse` and `ToString`.

Comment: @ken2k  I am actually fetching date in dd-mm-yyyy format from text box and want to insert it like yyyy/MM/dd in db.